# Round a Python list of numbers and maintain their sum

Tags: python, numpy, sum, rounding

I have a list or an array of decimal numbers in Python.  I need to round them to the nearest 2 decimal places as these are monetary amounts.  But, I need the overall sum to be maintained, i.e. the sum of the original array rounded to 2 decimal places must be equal to the sum of the rounded elements of the array.

Here's my code so far:

```
myOriginalList = [27226.94982, 193.0595233, 1764.3094, 12625.8607, 26714.67907, 18970.35388, 12725.41407, 23589.93271, 27948.40386, 23767.83261, 12449.81318]
originalTotal = round(sum(myOriginalList), 2)
# Answer = 187976.61

# Using numpy
myRoundedList = numpy.array(myOriginalList).round(2)
# New Array = [ 27226.95    193.06   1764.31  12625.86  26714.68  18970.35  12725.41 23589.93 27948.4   23767.83  12449.81]

newTotal = myRoundedList.sum()
# Answer = 187976.59
```

I need an efficient way of amending my new rounded array such that the sum is also 187976.61.  The 2 pence difference needs to be applied to items 7 and 6 as these have the greatest difference between the rounded entries and the original entries.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using floating-point numbers to represent monetary amounts. There are plenty of numbers, such as `0.10`, that `float` cannot represent exactly.

Comment: What's wrong with your numpy solution?  If I understand correctly, that's the answer you're looking for ...

Comment: @NPE: Isn't that what round is for? I mean, any uncertainty in the number 0.1 should be comparable to machine precision, right?

Comment: @BenDundee: If you are only using `float` for *storing* monetary amounts, and are aware of the issues, you are probably OK. However, the moment you start doing computations is the moment you're opening a major can of worms.

Answer (score 10):

As noted in an [answer by kettlehell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51451847/832230), consider the PyPI package [`iteround`](https://pypi.org/project/iteround/). It does not internally use NumPy, however.

```
>>> from iteround import saferound
>>> saferound([1.0, 2.1, 3.6], places=0)
[1.0, 2.0, 4.0]
```

Answer (score 8):

The first step is to calculate the error between the desired result and the actual sum:

```
>>> error = originalTotal - sum(myRoundedList)
>>> error
0.01999999996041879
```

This can be either positive or negative. Since every item in `myRoundedList` is within 0.005 of the actual value, this error will be less than 0.01 per item of the original array. You can simply divide by 0.01 and round to get the number of items that must be adjusted:

```
>>> n = int(round(error / 0.01))
>>> n
2
```

Now all that's left is to select the items that should be adjusted. The optimal results come from adjusting those values that were closest to the boundary in the first place. You can find those by sorting by the difference between the original value and the rounded value.

```
>>> myNewList = myRoundedList[:]
>>> for _,i in sorted(((myOriginalList[i] - myRoundedList[i], i) for i in range(len(myOriginalList))), reverse=n>0)[:abs(n)]:
    myNewList[i] += math.copysign(0.01, n)

>>> myRoundedList
[27226.95, 193.06, 1764.31, 12625.86, 26714.68, 18970.35, 12725.41, 23589.93, 27948.4, 23767.83, 12449.81]
>>> myNewList
[27226.95, 193.06, 1764.31, 12625.86, 26714.68, 18970.359999999997, 12725.42, 23589.93, 27948.4, 23767.83, 12449.81]
>>> sum(myNewList)
187976.61
```

Answer (score 3):

I am late, but here is a general solution that works with numpy, which I have found to be ~100 times faster than other implementations proposed on this page:

```
def round_retain_sum(x):
    x = x*100 # We want 2 decimal precision
    N = np.round(np.sum(x)).astype(int)
    y = x.astype(int)
    M = np.sum(y)
    K = N - M 
    z = y-x 
    if K!=0:
        idx = np.argpartition(z,K)[:K]
        y[idx] += 1     
    return y/100.
```

EDIT NOTE: Must convert the input list into a NumPy array with np.array(x) as some of the methods/attributes don't work on lists. But it works once converted

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It will be helpful to see your timing experiments.

Comment: nice.  so the `argpartition` is finding the elements that got floor()d furthest (by `astype(int)`) in order to increment them and get back to the target rounded sum.   i.e. `set(np.argpartition(z, K)[:K]) == set(np.argsort(z)[:K])` but the former is faster

Answer (score 1):

With all the caveats about using floating point numbers:

```
delta_pence = int(np.rint((originalTotal - np.sum(myRoundedList))*100))
if delta_pence > 0:
    idx = np.argsort(myOriginalList - myRoundedList)[-delta_pence:]
    myRoundedList[idx] += 0.01
elif delta_pence < 0:
    idx = np.argsort(myOriginalList - myRoundedList)[:delta_pence]
    myRoundedList[idx] -= 0.01

>>> myRoundedList.sum()
187976.60999999999
```

Comment: In your example, when you have `8 * [0.001] + [0.009]`, you get `8 * [0.0] + [0.2]` which is same type of an error, that you appointed in my solution. Rounding is rounding.

Comment: @palooh That was a bug, thanks for spotting it! If you run it now, the outcome is `7 * [0.00] + 2 * [0.01]`, so that the extra pence are added minimizing the individual rounding errors.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you shouldn't use floats for storing money (use Decimals instead). But below I provide some quite generic solution - you need to store, accumulate and use the sum of differences in rounding. Some verbose (and not very pythonic ;-) example with your numbers:

```
# define your accuracy
decimal_positions = 2

numbers = [27226.94982, 193.0595233, 1764.3094, 12625.8607, 26714.67907, 18970.35388, 12725.41407, 23589.93271, 27948.40386, 23767.83261, 12449.81318]
print round(sum(numbers),decimal_positions)
>>> 187976.61

new_numbers = list()
rest = 0.0
for n in numbers:
    new_n = round(n + rest,decimal_positions)
    rest += n - new_n
    new_numbers.append( new_n )

print sum(new_numbers)
>>> 187976.61
```

Comment: If your first two numbers are `x.0049` and `y.0001`, your rounding method will convert them to `x.00` and `y.01`, which doesn't seem like the best thing to do.

Comment: Well, you can always sort the list by `abs(n % 0.01)` descending, but considering the _rounding_ maybe it's not so important...