# Rounding floats while maintaining total sum equal

Tags: python

I have a list of floats that add up to an integer. For circumstantial reasons, I have to iterate using a `for` loop x times, x being each float in the list, but since the argument for the `range()` function must be an integer, each float must be rounded. However, I want the total number of loops to remain equal to the sum of the original floats, which doesn't usually add up to the sum of the rounded numbers. How would you solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Why does that matter? Please post your code.

Comment: 1) Sort floats by absolute distance to next integer; 2) round numbers to next int one at a time; 3) as soon as you have no other choice whether to round up or down to maintain the sum, round in the "wrong" direction. This should minimize the error when rounding.

Comment: You want to run a `for` loop for a value that is float, that doesn't make sense. You have to round-off your value to an `int`. What you can do is round-off only the final value to keep the `error-delta` minimum.

Comment: However, depending on the actual usecase, it might be easier and much more reasonable to just include a disclaimer "sums might not add up to X due to rounding".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, this is going to be a bit mathematical:

You have a series of real numbers Xi
Their sum equals N
sum(Xi) = N

Let's break each real number to its floor integer and residual real part (between 0 and 1): Xi = Ri + fi

Now, you need a series of integers Yi that are as close to Xi, but are integers and also sum to N. We can break them like this: Yi = Ri + Fi (where Fi is an integer either 0 or 1).

Now we need that:
sum(Yi) = sum(Xi) = N

If you break that, you'll get this equation as a requirement for the solution:
sum(Fi) = sum(fi) = N - sum(Ri)

Let's denote: K = N - sum(Ri)

Now the solution is simple, choose the K elements which have the largest fi values, and assign their corresponding Fi to 1; assign the other Fi to 0.

Now you have your values for Yi which in your case are the loop sizes

Here's the code for it:

```
def round_series_retain_integer_sum(xs):
    N = sum(xs)
    Rs = [round(x) for x in xs]
    K = N - sum(Rs)
    assert K == round(K)
    fs = [x - round(x) for x in xs]
    indices = [i for order, (e, i) in enumerate(reversed(sorted((e,i) for i,e in enumerate(fs)))) if order < K]
    ys = [R + 1 if i in indices else R for i,R in enumerate(Rs)]
    return ys


xs = [5.2, 3.4, 2.1, 7.3, 3.25, 6.25, 8.2, 9.1, 10.1, 55.1]
ys = round_series_retain_integer_sum(xs)

print xs, sum(xs)
print ys, sum(ys)
```

I think I don't have any bugs, I hope you get the idea even if so

Comment: After some testing, it appears that with very long floats (10+ decimals) it gets messed up because of floating-point number errors. This probably doesn't have a solution then, right? I know this is a separate issue, but I'd like to know your thoughts on it anyway. Thank you!

Comment: Nevermind, changing the calls to round() to int() solved it

Comment: Nitpick: mathematically speaking, a series is an infinite sum. What you have here is a *sequence*.

Comment: this example doesn't work well for corner cases like [0.5,0.5,1]

to patch this, add some lines:
```
    # handle the corner case of elements having 0.5:
    indices_elements_halving_unity = [i for i in range(len(xs)) if xs[i] % 1 == 0.5]
    if len(indices_elements_halving_unity) % 2 == 0:
        for i in indices_elements_halving_unity:
            if i % 2 == 0:
                xs[i] = xs[i] - epsilon()
            else:
                xs[i] = xs[i] + epsilon()
```
with epsilon() returning a small number like 0.000001

Answer (score 13):

I recently had to solve a similar problem and decided it was something common enough to various projects of mine to generalize a python solution and package it. Check out [`iteround`](https://pypi.org/project/iteround/).