# Round Lists While Maintaining Sum Across ALL Lists

Tags: python

[I have seen where we can round elements in a single list while maintaining overall list sum value.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44737874/rounding-floats-while-maintaining-total-sum-equal/44740221#44740221)

However, what if I have multiple lists and am trying to round individual elements in each list while maintaining the sum across ALL of the lists?

For example, we are given:

```
a = [4.1, 5.9, 10.3]
b = [3.2, 3.2, 4.5]
c = [10.1, 8.8, 7.4]
```

All lists together sum to 57.5

How would I round each element in each list *while* ensuring all lists together still sum to 57 or 58?

For my purposes, there are some relaxed constraints that may make this easier:

- The sum of all rounded lists together can be up to 5% different from the unrounded (for example, the 57.5 can be as little as 55 or as much as 60 (but, ideally, the sum is +/- 1 [57 or 58]).
- it is OK if individual elements change more than +/- 1 (but, ideally, each element is changed by <1.).

Comment: If you can round each list and keep the sum... you can do that to every list individually, and you will keep the overall sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the fact that you have multiple lists matters. It's the same situation as in the question you linked - treat all elements as if they are in one list then use calculated values in orignal lists. I don't really see any issue with this solution.