# Python - How to output a numpy array of probabilities with certain precision and remain its sum

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, precision, probability

I have a numpy array of 6 probabilities which come from pytorch softmax function.

```
[0.055709425,0.04365404,0.008613999,0.0022386343,0.0037478858,0.88603604]
```

I want to convert all 6 float numbers to string to represent a score output,
and all of them need to be rounded to a certain precision, say 4.
I used the following code to get the output text:

```
','.join(f'{x:.4f}' for x in scores)  # scores is the array above
```

and the output is

```
0.0557,0.0437,0.0086,0.0022,0.0037,0.8860
```

which sums up to 0.9999 instead of 1.0. And I have a bunch of arrays like this one but sums up to either 0.9999 or 1.0001.
So my question is, how do I get the output that sums up exactly to 1.0?
I know it's a floating point computation problem. What am I missing, some rounding operation or some adjustment?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Round 5 of them.  The 6th is 1. minus the sum if the 5 rounded results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round a Python list of numbers and maintain their sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769948/round-a-python-list-of-numbers-and-maintain-their-sum)

Answer (score 1):

You can round off to 2 decimal places, to reduce that error:

For example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0.055709425,0.04365404,0.008613999,0.0022386343,0.0037478858,0.88603604])
print(sum(a))
```

Output:

```
1.0000000241
```

Now:

```
new_array = [round(x,2) for x in a]
print(sum(new_array))
```

Output:

```
1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

To optimise the way each individual number is rounded up or down in order to get the sum equal to 1, you could do the following:

1. multiply all numbers so to move the required decimals before the decimal point, and then round them all down (`int`)
2. see how many units you come short to get to the desired sum. Let's call this `carry`
3. sort the numbers by descending difference from their rounded-down values
4. choose the first `carry` entries from that sorted list, and add 1 to them, so that now the sum is as desired.
5. restore the original order and divide the numbers to move their digits into their fractional parts again.

Here is an implementation of that idea:

```
def roundall(scores, decimalplaces):
    # Coefficient to multiply with in order to keep the desired number of decimal digits
    coeff = 10**decimalplaces
    # Convert to integers and keep track of the original index 
    #    and the amount that was dropped by flooring
    lst = sorted((int(score * coeff) - score * coeff, i, int(score * coeff)) 
                  for i, score in enumerate(scores))
    # How many units have we lost by truncating?
    carry = -round(sum(tup[0] for tup in lst))
    # Distribute the carry over the numbers having the greatest truncation costs
    return [value / coeff 
            for i, value in sorted((i, value + int(carry > j)) 
                                   for j, (overflow, i, value) in enumerate(lst))]
```

Here is how you would call it for your example:

```
scores = [0.055709425,0.04365404,0.008613999,0.0022386343,0.0037478858,0.88603604]
result = roundall(scores, 4)
print(result)
```

This outputs:

```
[0.0557, 0.0437, 0.0086, 0.0022, 0.0038, 0.886]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a linear optimization where you want to minimize errors e1, e2, e3.. e6  such that
(p1+ e1) + (p2+e2) + .. + (p6+e6) = 1

Here
e1 e2.. can take values as 0.0001 or -0.0001

e1, e2,e3 etc are the errors.
p1, p2, ..p6 are your rounded probabilities
(p1+e1), (p2+e2), etc are your new probabilities

You can achieve this using PuLP linear programming package in Python